# When I am reading a API in java I get ÃŽ in place of Î in a string. What should I do?

Tags: java, string, character-encoding

The string **Île-de-France** got converted into **ÃŽle-de-France**.

How should I get the original one in java?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an encoding issue. It may be that you encode the data incorrectly for transmission, storage or retrieval.

The best policy is to stick to a consistent Unicode encoding, such as UTF-8  for serialization, deserialization and storage of your data.

Search the w3.org website for I18n and Charmod. For more information. (I'm answering from my mobile while on holiday or I would give you links)

Comment: thanks for the answer, its been troubleshooted now as coverting to WINDOWS-1252 from UTF-8 encoding has done the work